# My WordPress Link not displayed on LinkedIn

Tags: html, wordpress, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a website created with wordpress.
Indeed, I would like to have my picture and a description but it shows nothing :

[image]

I thought I have put the right og codes :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://dotcamp.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/article-blockchain-1.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Infographie : l&rsquo;écosystème blockchain français | DOT Camp" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Après un démarrage lent, l&rsquo;écosystème français de la blockchain bouge de plus en plus vite. Des ICO&rsquo;s significatives lèvent des fonds avec succès, citons Talao, IExec et LGO GROUP (ex Legolas)." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://dotcamp.fr/infographie-lecosysteme-blockchain-francais/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="DOT Camp" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2018-06-12T22:21+02:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2018-09-14T16:21+02:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2018-09-14T16:21+02:00" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Infographie : l&rsquo;écosystème blockchain français | DOT Camp" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Après un démarrage lent, l&rsquo;écosystème français de la blockchain bouge de plus en plus vite. Des ICO&rsquo;s significatives lèvent des fonds avec succès, citons Talao, IExec et LGO GROUP (ex Legolas)." />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://dotcamp.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/article-blockchain-1.png" />
<meta name="twitter:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta name="twitter:image:height" content="630" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://dotcamp.fr/infographie-lecosysteme-blockchain-francais/" />
```

Is the anybody seeing what's wrong ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: have you tried the post inspector already ? you have to put in the link you want to share into the post inspector : https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

Comment: Yes I had, I have a 503 error on URL redirect trail, but It is ok when displayed on my browser ...

Comment: what do you mean with "displayed on my browser" because a 503 is a Service unavailable Error. ( assuming 503 is the status-code )

Comment: When I put the url in my address bar, it works properly, it doesn't show 503 error.

Comment: I think this could be a problem with cloudflare, our CDN. We have created a SSL certificate with it, and when i desactivate the CDN, it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a problem with my CDN. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

so the only thing i can imagine that could be the problem is :

> The first time that LinkedIn's crawlers visit a webpage when asked to
>   share content via a URL, the data it finds (Open Graph values or our
>   own analysis) will be cached for a period of approximately 7 days.
>
> This means that if you subsequently change the article's description,
>   upload a new image, fix a typo in the title, etc., you will not see
>   the change represented during any subsequent attempts to share the
>   page until the cache has expired and the crawler is forced to revisit
>   the page to retrieve fresh content.
>
> If you make API calls that directly provide the content to be shared
>   rather than by a URL that requires analysis, LinkedIn will always use
>   the values you provide.

source: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Comment: Hum, interesting, but I don't think so. I retried posting after more of 7 days ...

Comment: well apparently there is a bug in LinkedIn crawling proces, linkedin is looking into this.